# DatagridView Highlight Event - WINFORM C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, datagridviewcolumn

I have a combobox which is connected to the database so I populate the value of my combobox based on what's in my database. my combobox is another FORM from the datagrid. So here's I want to achieve.

form1 = datagrid (based on the database)
form2 = combobox (based on the database)

I want that If I highlight a certain row (My selection mode = fullrowselect) and press a button the comboBox will automatically point to that row.

for ex.
datagrid

1. name: Joe (highlighted)
2. *user clicks the button whch in my case is edit
3. *load edit form
4. comboBox.SelectedIndex is = highlighted row (which the user clicks)

I can show you my code if it helps. thanks :))

THANKS! :))

Comment: pass the row index to combobox

Comment: ok. I'll try. is there a selectedRowIndex method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set in the following ways, you can pass the value Joe to the other form via a parameter in the constructor. This could be then used to select you required value in the `ComboBox`

`comboBox2.SelectedIndex = comboBox2.Items.IndexOf("Joe");`

`comboBox2.SelectedText = "Three";` // or SelectedValue depending on how you are binding

**EDIT**
Avoid accessing the grid directly from the other form, expose the value required as a property or better pass it to the new form as parameter.

Joe could be the value of the cell like `dataGridView2.CurrentRow[0].FormattedValue` and pass this to the new form constructor like `new Form2(object datagridvalue)`. Then use the value in the form later on.

Comment: Joe should be a variable. Which means it is dependent to what the user clicks/highlighted

Comment: indeed it would be a variable