# DatagridView Selected Row Error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, combobox

What is wrong w/my code?

```
this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = _f3.dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

my datagrid is in form3 and my combobox is in form 2. HOW could I implement something like this?

Comment: I believe you should be checking for the value contained in the cell, like `dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].FormattedValue` or better use `CurrentRow`, post that find the value in the combobox and set the selected index

Comment: Thanks sir, but I can't access datagridview2 and I dont know how to access it. I keep changing the access modifier of the datagrid but the error doesn't go away. it says that datagridview2 is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: See [My Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426053/datagridview-highlight-event-winform-c-sharp) to your previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you declare one public integer in form2 and when you want to get the selected row index of the datagridview you can use the [CurrentRowIndex property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.currentrowindex.aspx) to get the index of the datagridview selected row like, in form3 you get the selectedindex global varaible from form2 and assign the CurrentRowIndex, or declare a public method which should return the selected row index when ever required

In form2 you write something like

```
  private int selectedindex {get; set;}
    selectedindex = _f3.GetSelectedIndex();
    this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = selectedindex;
```

In form3 you write the method like

```
 public int GetSelectedIndex()
    {
         int selectedIndex = 0;
         try
         {
           if(dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
           {
              selectedIndex = dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index;
           }
         }
         catch
         {
          return 0;
         }
      return selectedIndex;
    }
```

EDIT:

You can use instead

```
dataGridview2.CurrentRow.Index
```

In form3 under the SelectionChanged event of datagridview you do the following thing

```
    private void dataGridView2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectedindex = dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index;
    }
```

and also declare the selectedindex as an integer as a public variable like

```
public int selectedindex {get; set;}
```

and in form2 directly get the selectedindex by using the global variable like below,

```
this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = _f3.selectedindex;
```

get the selectedindex when ever required.

Comment: I cant still access dataGridView2.. theres an error in the part dataGridView2... same error as stated above. T_T

Comment: I'm having 2 errors mr. sai. 1st is Warning. The class name '?' is not a valid identifier for this language. 
2nd is 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentRowIndex' and no extension method..

Comment: another error appeared. T_T it says {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: @rjtubera, see the code now. I have added one if() {} condition there see it. It happens when ever now row is selected.

Comment: three errors occured: 1st:The variable 'ex' is declared but never used. 2nd: Warning The class name '?' is not a valid identifier for this language. 3rd:'HMS.Main.Form3.GetSelectedIndex()': not all code paths return a value.

Comment: Its not error, but a warning it will not effect your output. apart that what errors you are getting. See the code again now I will modify it.

Comment: it's doesn't change anything. My combobox is always pointing to index 0 whenever I highlight in my datagrid. T_T

Comment: I've put the value of the selectedindex in my form 2 to a textbox but the value is always at 0 even if I select/highlight another row.

Comment: more error occured... where will I put that public int selectedindex {get; set;} in form 3?

Comment: at start of the form code before constructor of form, common man even you dont know this???

Comment: I've done that but there is still an error. I just want to clarify because an error is occuring. it says {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} in the selection changed event handler

Comment: Please, cross check every thing in your code. Because, the same thing which I included in SelectionChanged event is working in my case, why not in yours? if you include SelectionChanged then remove the GetSelectedIndex() method from your code and try.

Comment: Yes. It has no error. But what will I put in my form2? Thanks for helping me mr. sai.

Comment: Ok, any how I again edited the post ignore the code parts which I have given before Edit, and try with the code after Edit.

Comment: Good News: No error encountered Bad News: the value did not changed. it is still set to 0. Sir. Did you also tried to do this? Did it work in your case?

Comment: The value will be 0 when now row selected, because the public int variable by default contains 0, put a break point inside the SelectionChanged event and see whether the selected row index is assigned or not.

Comment: Ive already solved the problem sir. THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Modifiers` property of datagridview2 to `Public`

Comment: I've already changed it. I even used all of the modifiers available. but still, the error won't go away.